# passing values from command line to project property in SoapUI

Tags: soapui

I have some project properties with following names:

```
ApplicationServer 
WebbServer 
ServiceEndpoint
```

in my bat-file I try following:

```
set SOAPUI_HOME="C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-Pro-5.1.2"

call %SOAPUI_HOME%\bin\testrunner.bat ^    
    -j ^
    -fC:\Temp\Premie ^
    -R"JUnit-Style HTML Report" ^
    -R"JUnit-Style HTML Report" ^
    -EDefault ^
    -PApplicationServer ^
    -P= ^
    -PTESTAPPLICATIONSERVER ^
    -PWebbServer ^
    -P= ^
    -PTESTWEBBSERVER ^
    -PServiceEndpoint ^
    -P= ^
    -PURLTOTEST ^
    "C:\TEMP\soapui-project.xml"
```

When I run the test from command line, the properties are not being updated from values in bat-file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I reformatted the code _you_ posted for legibility. Note: In `.bat`, the `^` character means: "continued on next line". Can you now see the errors?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you were trying with `-P` option to testrunner utility which is right way  as per soapui [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-functional-tests.html). But not passing values correctly.

> P : Sets project property with name=value, e.g. -Pendpoint=Value1 -PsomeOtherProperty=value2

More info [here](http://readyapi.smartbear.com/features/automation/testrunner/cli)

> If the value includes spaces, enclose the entire argument in quotes. To override several variable values, specify the -P argument several times.

In your case, if you want to pass the value `JBOSS` to project property `ApplicationServer`, then here you go:

`testrunner.bas -PApplicationServer=JBOSS <append other options one after the other separated by a space>`

**UPDATE: based on comments:**
You are not using it properly which I understand from your above post.

Here is modified command:

- removed repeating *-R*
- added value between quotes for hostname
- removed extra spaces between name and value.

```
testrunner.bat -j -f "C:\Temp\" -R "JUnit-Style HTML Report" -PAppServer=TESTAPP -PWebbServer=TEST -PServiceEndpoint="services.test.com" -PdbServer=TESTDb "C:\SoapUI\soapui-project.xml"
```

Comment: I got it to work! I did like this: -P AppServer=TEST -P WebbServer=TESTWEBB

Comment: Thanks Rao it helped a lot :-)

Comment: @Oliver, glad to know that it helped.